# Copy / Move One SAP Client From One System to another System

Tags: sap-basis

We have one SAP system in the US (let's call it `TKIJVPL1`), this system has an SAP client `241`.  We have another SAP system in Germany (lets call it `Lockweiler`).
We need to move this client `241` from our `TKIJVPL1` server to this new server.

Can I simply use transaction `SCC8`?  It says client export, but when I look at the options, it says

- Source client : `241` (which is good),
- Profile Name `SAP_ALL` (which is also good as I need all data),
- but Target System all that is coming up is `PL1` / `QL1`.

What is the easiest way to export one client from one system to another system in SAP system?

Or I would rather export it to a hard drive, take these files place them on a DVD and mail them to Germany.  But I do not see an export to the local disk transaction???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working.

You still need to use transaction SCC8, it could potentially take 8-20+ hours doing a client export.  As it is exporting you need to look at the folder \usr\sap\trans\data and in there SAP will create some files with the system name as an extension.  In my case it created files like RT03292.PL1 and a few others.

Now one needs to take these files to do an import...

Here are some good links pertaining to this:

http://basissap.blogspot.com/2008/05/what-is-client-copy.html

http://forums.sdn.sap.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1713405&tstart=0

**Make sure you look at /usr/sap/trans/data for the data files (usually start with R).
Also make sure you look at /usr/sap/trans/cofiles (usually starts with a K).**